# pandas.DataFrame.idxmin - how to handle equal values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(index=["Index_1","Index_2","Index_3","Index_4","Index_5","Index_6","Index_7"],
                   columns=["Header_1","Header_2","Rank_1","Rank_2"], data=[[4.06,4.34,1,1],[3.30,2.35,2,3],
                    [3.26,1.02,3,7],[3.14,2.40,4,2],[2.61,1.81,5,5],[2.52,2.33,6,4],[2.36,1.62,7,6]])
```

which results in:

```
         Header_1   Header_2    Rank_1  Rank_2
Index_1    4.06      4.34          1      1
Index_2    3.30      2.35          2      3
Index_3    3.26      1.02          3      7
Index_4    3.14      2.40          4      2
Index_5    2.61      1.81          5      5
Index_6    2.52      2.33          6      4
Index_7    2.36      1.62          7      6
```

The Rank columns (_1,_2) show the ranking of the values (say returns) in the header columns (_1,_2) when the latter are sorted in descending order. For example at `Index_2 , Header 1` - we have the second highest value of 3.3 within `Header_1` column , therefore the rank of 2 at column `Rank_1`.

For each Index (_1,_2,_3,_4....) I want to map either `Rank_1 or Rank_2` depending on where the minimum value is; In essence this achieved via `pandas.DataFrame.idxmin`.
If I use:  `frame.iloc[:,[2,3]].idxmin(axis=1)`  I arrive at:

```
Index_1    Rank_1
Index_2    Rank_1
Index_3    Rank_1
Index_4    Rank_2
Index_5    Rank_1
Index_6    Rank_2
Index_7    Rank_2
```

This is more or less the desired output; yet when there are equal ranks in `Rank_1 and Rank_2` columns, such as at `Index_1 or Index_5` I want the algorithm to check also the two Header columns and make final decision based on the highest value from `Header_1 or Header_2`. So at `Index_1` we see that the ranks are equal (1); however `Header_2` contains the higher value (4.34) compared to `Header_1` (4.06). Therefore I would expect the final output to be as follows:

```
Index_1    Rank_2
Index_2    Rank_1
Index_3    Rank_1
Index_4    Rank_2
Index_5    Rank_1
Index_6    Rank_2
Index_7    Rank_2
```

Note: the difference at the last two outputs is just at `Index_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add or subtract an `epsilon` value to `Rank_1` according to `Header_1 < Header_2` or not:

```
eps = 0.000001

out = frame.assign(Rank_1=np.where(df['Header_1'] < df['Header_2'],
                                   df['Rank_1'] + eps, df['Rank_1'] - eps)
                  ).iloc[:,[2,3]].idxmin(axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
Index_1    Rank_2
Index_2    Rank_1
Index_3    Rank_1
Index_4    Rank_2
Index_5    Rank_1
Index_6    Rank_2
Index_7    Rank_2
dtype: object
```